# how to get dynamic id values of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a combo box. When I select a value from combobox, it prints some results below. I have a link to delete every single results. So when I click 'Delete' link, the particular result should be deleted. I am using jquery to delete process. What I really want is, the results are generated dynamically, so every single delete link will have particular id values. I wanna know how can I get the particular result to delete when I click particular 'Delete' link as every result will have a unique id. how can i get it from jquery.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  include("db.php");
  $make_id = $_GET['make_id'];
  $sql = mysql_query("select model_id, model from models where make_ID = $make_id");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td id='" . $row['model_id'] . "' class='model_id_class' width='200'>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td width='50'>" . "<a href='delete_model.php' id='delete_class'>" . "Delete" . "</a>" . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated XHTML to make the question more comprehensive?

Comment: <?php 
 include("db.php");
 
 $make_id = $_GET['make_id'];
 
 $sql = mysql_query("select  model_id, model from models where make_ID = $make_id");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td id='".$row['model_id']."' class='model_id_class' width='200'>".$row['model']."</td>";
  echo "<td width='50'>"."<a href='delete_model.php' id='delete_class'>"."Delete"."</a>"."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 
?>

The UI will be generated from this code. I need to get the $row['model_id'] value to use with the 'Delete' link

Comment: Please add the code block to the question next time. It's really hard to read huge codeblocks on comments

Comment: Im really sorry, this is ma first time asking question on a forum, and thanks a lot to let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in your comment your output might be something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td id="x">
    result
  </td>
  <td>
    <a class="delete_class">delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Since it's all in the same tr:

```
$('.delete_class').live('click',function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you create a `<a>` delete link inside the dynamically produced content (say a `<span>`) created  you could do something like

```
<span>A result generated dynamically 
      <a href='#' onclick='$(this).parent().remove()'>delete this result</a>
</span>
```

Dunno if this comes close to answering your question...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, doing such stuff in j-query, you should try to relate link and result - that makes it simpler. Something like

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="resultArea">
     ....
   </div>

   <a href="#" class="deleteLink">Delete</a>

</div>
```

And then script such as below would link them together

```
$('.container').each(function() {

  var container = $(this);
  var result = container.find('.resultArea');
  var link = container.find('.deleteLink');

  link.onClick(function() { // code to remove });

});
```

Comment: Since he is dynamically adding the elements you cannot just bind all the click events on page load. 
You either need to use .live or bind every time a new delete button/link is added to the DOM.

Comment: @Keyo, he is not creating elements from java-script (IMO). When he mentions dynamic ids - he just meant to say ids are not fixed text because they are getting created from server side.

Comment: Yeah the as id's i've mentioned here is a database value and im assigning it to every relevant rows

Answer (score 0):

> I have a link to delete every single results.
>   Does this mean a delete link for each thing you want to delete? That's what I'm assuming here.

I used this on some recent work. It uses .live, otherwise you would need to bind click events every time you add something that has a delete button. Basically clicking anything with class="remove" will remove the parent row.

```
$('a.remove').live('click', function() {
       $(this).parent('tr').fadeOut(500, function() {
           $(this).remove();
       });

});
```